# Different model instance representation for controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

I wondering is there a way to represent model differently (or probably control access on fields level) depending on it's (model instance) state and controller using it.

**Example:**

Imagine we have an `Order` model with `product_id`, `count`, `price` and `status` fields. 
`status` could be one of: `:new`, `:confirmed`, `:accepted`, `:cancelled`, `:delivered` and `:closed`.

Application can access `Order` from, say, two controllers `CustomerOrdersController` and `SellerOrdersController`. So, `CustomerOrdersController` could create and edit orders. But able to change only `count` field.  On the other hand `SellerOrdersController` could edit orders. But able to change only price field. I.e. it would be great if instance of `Order` class that `CustomerOrdersController` working with have no `price=` method. Same for `count=`(`product=`) and `SellerOrderController`.

Further more set of columns permitted to edit depends on status field (probably work for some state machine).

So, the question is: **how would you do this in your app?**

**PS**

I think about some `ActiveModel` proxy objects for `ActiveRecord` instances, but do not know actually will it work or not. Consider:

```
class CustomerOrderProxy < ActiveModel::Base end
class SellerOrderProxy < ActiveModel::Base end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def wrap_proxy(controller_user)
    controller_user == CustomerOrdersController ? CustomerOrderProxy(self) : SellerOrderProxy(self)
  end
end
```

Another approach would be to do tons of checks and `params` validations inside controller actions, but I do not want to. I believe in "Fat model - skinny controller" :)

**PPS**

I know that ruby have plenty state machine plugins, but AFAI understand they define only transitions, not method set (i.e. representation) of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found appropriate solution: in Ryan Bates's screencast [Dynamic attr_accessible](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible)

Update:
In Rails 3.1 `update_attributes(params[:order], role)` could be used. Check out [rails api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html). Though it cannot be used to change access control according to object's state.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like simple access control. Access is granted based on the authorized user, not which controller is being used. Take a look at the [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem for implementing clean, declarative access control for your AR objects.

Comment: I'm already using CanCan, but it's only restrict access on controller actions level. I need to hide ability to change particular attribute of particular AR object. E.g. `order = Order.first(1).wrap(CustomerOrdersController); order.price= 1 # this will raise NoMethodError or something like this`